# cpp too many initializers - struct in struct in array

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

I'm new to cpp since a few days and struggling with the following definition:

```
struct menuItem {
    char* name;
    int value;
};

struct topMenu {
    int menuIcon;
    char* Name;
    menuItem item[];
};

topMenu menuRoot[] = {
    { 0, "File", 
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"New ...", 4},
        {"Close", 1},
        {"Exit", 3}

    },
    { 0, "Edit", 
        {"Cut ", 3},
        {"Copy", 8},
        {"Paste", 2},
        {"Find", 1},
        {"Replace", 6}

    },
    { 0, "Help", 
        {"Help", 7},
        {"About", 9},
        {"Update ..", 9}
    }  
};
```

I receive the error

```
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'menuItem [0]'
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'topMenu'
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'menuItem [0]'
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'topMenu'
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'menuItem [0]'
33:1: error: too many initializers for 'topMenu'
```

Sorry, i'm a little bit stuck ... maybe its just to late :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Off topic] Do not use a `char*` to point to string literals.  It was deprecated in C++03 and removed in C++11.  Either use a `const char*` or a `std::string`/`std::string_view`

Comment: You need to wrap each menuItem array in an additional ```{``` (```{{"Help", 7},
        {"About", 9},
        {"Update ..", 9}}```).

Comment: What do you expect from `menuItem item[];`? should it be `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Remember that size of arrays in C++ has to be determined at compile time.

Comment: And in C, flexible array members can generally only be used with dynamically allocated structures, not an array of structures, because you have to allocate enough additional memory for the flexible array.

Comment: `menuItem item[];` is not allowed in Standard C++, you must specify a size (or use a different construct altogether)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, wrap the menuItem item[] array in {} because currently it thinks there are many arrays rather than just one.

Next, change the char * to const char * as was mentioned.

Now for the flexible  amount of menuItem structs, use a vector rather than an array.

```
#include <vector> 

struct menuItem {
    const char *name;
    int value;
};

struct topMenu {
    int menuIcon;
    const char *Name;
    std::vector<menuItem> item;
};

topMenu menuRoot[] = {
    { 0, "File", {
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"Open ...", 1},
    }
    },
    { 0, "Help", {
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"Open ...", 1},
        {"Open ...", 1}, }
    }
};
```

Comment: My bad, just laziness on my part.

Comment: The menu is basically static (won't be changed during runtime ( - yet)). Therefore i could set all sizes. But i just thought there was another way.  Since it will be use on an embedded system, i've care about memory. Thanks!